# Spring boot: Logback logs only from one module

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, logging, logback

I have a (Maven) multi module Spring Boot application running in Tomcat 9. Logback is configured with external logback.xml.

For some reason Logback is only logging from the the "main module" where the Spring application is. This main module is actually the also the module which is packaged as WAR which contains the rest of the modules.

I can see all the logged lines in the tomcat9-stdout.log but not in the log file defined in the logback configuration. Only the main module's log lines are showing up there.

What could be the reason for this kind of behaviour?

Comment: Could you please provide your `pom.xml` and `logback.xml` files?

Comment: I have seen weirdness like this when both `commons-logging` and `jcl-over-slf4j` are on the classpath together. Excluding `commons-logging` from the classpath often helps.

Comment: Added as an answer so you can accept and let everyone else know how to fix going forward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen weirdness like this when both commons-logging and jcl-over-slf4j are on the classpath together. Excluding commons-logging from the classpath often helps.

Comment: Indeed, excluding the commons-logging, help showing a lot of logs